# C# control the alignment of data

Tags: c#, interop

In C++ you can use `__declspec( align( # ) )` declarator to control the alignment of user-defined data. How can do this for C#. I have two procedures written on Assembler in my dll. Arguments for procedures (two arrays) should be aligned on 16 bytes. For C++ it works fine.

I just used declarations

```
__declspec( align( 16 ) )
double a[2]={10.2,10.6};
```

Comment: maybe you should tell us what you want to do rather than (or in addition to) how you would do it in another language.

Comment: @Servy: Quite frankly I thought he was pretty clear as to what he wants to do; providing an example in a different language is normal.

Comment: @ChrisLively It's not wrong, I just don't consider it sufficient.  You limit responses to people who are familiar with the functionality of the other language.  A direct port also isn't always idea between languages.  If the underlying problem is know a solution more appropriate to the language may be used.

Answer (score 10):

If you are looking for managed to non-managed interop *(transmitting data between C#/.NET-based and C/C++/assembler-based software)*, you would use a combination of the [`StructLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute and the [`FieldOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 16)]
public class MyDataClass {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    double[] a;
}
```

According to MSDN:

> The System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute.Pack field determines the memory alignment of data fields of a target object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-6.0 is the updated link for documentation

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to the other answer, you do not need `LayoutKind.Explicit`, you just need `Pack`. You therefore don't need `FieldOffset` either.

You probably also want a `struct` not a `class`.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 16)]
public struct MyDataClass
{
    double[] a;
}
```

Note that this only helps for interop code, it will not help for managed code.