# Use Marshal.PtrToStructure to read a struct that is not normally aligned

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffi

Suppose that I have a struct like this:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int32_t field1;
    int32_t field2;
};
```

but due to some reasons it is aligned to 8 bytes instead of 4 bytes.

Will `Marshal.PtrToStructure` correctly handle it? If not, what should I do to marshal such struct?

Comment: Fifty-fifty odds that it is aligned to 8 by accident.  No, not a problem if it is not embedded in another struct or class.

Comment: @HansPassant well this is intentional, or more specifically I am trying to read the payload of a Rust Tagged Union, and because the whole payload struct is aligned to the largest alignment in the whole Union, for one union case the struct payload can often be aligned to a much bigger unit

Comment: Does [C# control the alignment of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10305548/3744182) answer your question?

Comment: @HansPassant Why should it be by accident, it's the default on 64-bit?

Comment: @dbc Partially, since I didn't find a way to add an attribute to a reflection-generated type :(
but anyway thanks

Comment: @ShanoaIce - your question mentions nothing about a *reflection-generated type* so it's unlikely that suggested answers will address this problem.  Please [edit] your question to share what your actual problem is, ideally via a [mcve].  See also [ask].

Answer (score -1):

In 64-bit programs the *packing* of sequential fields in a struct is on 8-byte boundaries.

But if you want to force it (eg you are working on 32-bit), you can add the `Pack` parameter to `StructLayout`, which you should have anyway

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
struct SomeStruct
{
    int32_t field1;
    int32_t field2;
};
```